# error C2440: <function-style-cast>: невозможно преобразовать "initializer list" в "Map<int,int>::Iterator"

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++, конструктор, итераторы

Имеется свой аналог std::map, работающий на бинарном дереве. Решил добавить итератор в Map. Не совсем понимаю код ошибки, а точнее как ее исправить. Очевидно лишь, что здесь проблема с конструктором, который не так воспринимает принимаемые параметры.

```
template<typename BinaryType>
class BinaryTree {
public:
    template<typename NodeType>
    struct Node {
        NodeType data;
        Node* left = nullptr;
        Node* right = nullptr;
        Node* parent = nullptr;
    };
private:
    Node<BinaryType>* root = nullptr;
public:
    BinaryTree() = default;
    ~BinaryTree() {} // clearTree

    const Node<BinaryType>* findMin() const {
        if (!root) return nullptr;
        Node<BinaryType>* temp = root;
        while (temp->left) temp = temp->left;
        return temp;
    }
    const Node<BinaryType>* findMax() const {
        if (!root) return nullptr;
        Node<BinaryType>* temp = root;
        while (temp->left) temp = temp->left;
        return temp;
    }

    const Node<BinaryType>* getRoot() const { return root; }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class Pair {
public:
    T first;
    U second;
public:
    Pair() = default;
    Pair(const T frst, const U scnd) : first(frst), second(scnd) {}
};

template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class Map {
private:
    BinaryTree<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>>* rootMap = nullptr;
public:
    class Iterator {
    private:
        friend class Map<KeyType, ValueType>;

        const BinaryTree::Node<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>>* current;
        const BinaryTree::Node<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>>* tree;

        Iterator(const BinaryTree::Node<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>>* cur, const BinaryTree::Node<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>>* tr)
            : current(cur), tree(tr) {}
    public:
        Iterator() : tree(nullptr) {}
        Iterator(Iterator& other) : current(other.current), tree(other.tree) {}
    };

    Map() { rootMap = new BinaryTree<Pair<KeyType, ValueType>>; }
    ~Map() { delete rootMap; };

    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(rootMap->findMin(), rootMap->getRoot()); }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator(nullptr, rootMap->getRoot()); }
};

int main() {
    Map<int, int> test;
    test.begin();
    return 0;
}
```

Полный текст ошибки:

> 1. error C2440: <function-style-cast>: невозможно преобразовать "initializer list" в "Map<int,int>::Iterator"
> 2. message : Ни один конструктор не смог принять исходный тип, либо разрешение перегрузки конструктора неоднозначно
> 3. message : во время компиляции функции-члена класс шаблон "Map<int,int>::Iterator Map<int,int>::end(void)"
> 4. message : выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "Map<int,int>::Iterator Map<int,int>::end(void)"
> 5. message : выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр класс шаблон функции "Map<int,int>"

Comment: Нужен [mcve]...